# The transition functions of a vector bundle are smooth

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $E$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds and let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a smooth surjective map. Suppose that $E$ is a smooth vector bundle of rank $k$ over $M$. Let $\Psi:\pi^{-1}\left(U\right)\rightarrow U\times\mathbb{R}^{k}$
  and $\Phi:\pi^{-1}\left(V\right)\rightarrow U\times\mathbb{R}^{k}$
  be local trivializations of $E$
  over $M$
  with $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$
 . Then there exists a smooth map $\tau:U\cap V\rightarrow\mbox{GL}\left(k,\mathbb{R}\right)$
  such that $\left(\Phi\circ\Psi^{-1}\right)\left(p,v\right)=\left(p,\tau\left(p\right)v\right)$
  for all $p\in U\cap V$
 , $v\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Here is my attempt of the proof (obtained with help from textbooks):

Let $\pi_{1}:\left(U\cap V\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k}$
  be the projection onto $U\cap V$
 . We have $\pi_{1}\circ\left(\Phi\circ\Psi^{-1}\right)=\pi_{1}$
 . This shows that $\left(\Phi\circ\Psi^{-1}\right)\left(p,v\right)=\left(p,\sigma\left(p,v\right)\right)$
  for all $p\in U\cap V$
 , $v\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$
 , where $\sigma:\left(U\cap V\right)\times\mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{k}$
  is a smooth map. Moreover, if $p$
  is fixed, the map defined by $v\longmapsto\sigma\left(p,v\right)$
  is a linear isomorphism. So there exists a function $\tau:U\cap V\rightarrow\mbox{GL}\left(k,\mathbb{R}\right)$
  such that $\sigma\left(p,v\right)=\tau\left(p\right)v$
 . We need to show that $\tau$
  is smooth. Let $e_{1}
 ,...,e_{k}$
  be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{k}$
  and let $\varepsilon_{1},
 ...,\varepsilon_{k}$
  be the dual basis for $\mathbb{R}^{k}$
 . Let $\tau_{i,j}\left(p\right)$
  be the $\left(i,j\right)$
  entry of the matrix $\tau\left(p\right)$
 . Then $\tau_{i,j}\left(p\right)=\varepsilon_{i}\left(\tau\left(p\right)e_{j}\right)=\varepsilon_{i}\left(\sigma\left(p,e_{j}\right)\right)$ Since it is a composition of smooth maps, $\tau_{i,j}$
  is smooth. Therefore $\tau$
  is smooth.

Is the proof correct?